# MouseDoubleClick event in c# treeview only occur when node is double clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

Event only occur when node is double clicked but i want to trigger double click even when no node is present in treeview.
I want to copy data from another treeview so event is required to trigger.

Comment: _I want to copy data from another treeview so event is required to trigger._ Sounds like a non-intuitive UI.

Comment: I know but it is client requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to achieve it by subscribing to `MouseUp` event.

```
private DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;

private void treeView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var t2 = t1;
    t1 = DateTime.Now;

    if ((t1 - t2).TotalMilliseconds <= SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime)
    {
        TreeViewHitTestInfo hti = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);

        if (hti.Node == null || !hti.Node.Bounds.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("empty area double-click");
        }
    }
}
```